# What would be a list of common website expenses?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, website-design, security-certificate

For example: seo; web-development; site-maintenance; hosting; domain; ssl-certificate; etc.

***_*__*UPDATES*__*_***

**FROM_ME:** Stock-Photos; Logo; Legal; eCommerce_Shopping-Cart

**FROM_Lèse_majesté:** IP-for-SSL-CERT; Merchant-Account; Payment-Gateway_setup,fees; website-design_template,customization; CMS-Customization; ADs_PPC

Comment: I think this should be a community wiki

Comment: agreed, made it so...

Comment: community wiki: "This post is community owned as of 5 mins ago. Votes do not generate reputation, and it can be edited by users with 100 rep" -- What does this mean?

Comment: It means that the post is community owned. Votes no longer generate reputation. If you have 100 rep or more, you can edit this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**

Re-reading the question, I think I should have just listed the different types of *possible* expenses rather than calculating the costs of different types of sites, so I'll try to do that now:

- Domain registration (annual)
- web hosting (monthly)
- unique IP + SSL add-on (monthly/annual)
- payment gateway (monthly + setup fee)
- merchant account (monthly + setup fee)
- design (one-off)
- development (one-off)
- usability testing (one-off)
- SEM or PPC advertising (monthly)

  - one-off SEM costs like directory listing
- analytics (monthly)

For businesses, there may be other expenses like e-mail marketing services, online PR platforms, competitive analysis tools/services, and auxiliary marketing research services.

Comment: @Lèse_majesté: Thanks, lots of info in your reply! So, yes, I've got lots of experience, been making websites over 15 years... just asking questions for myself and to get a better feel of how PW-SX works. Added your items to my question, and credited you. Again, thanks!

Comment: @blunders: yea, I realized that I wasn't answering the question you asked, so I simplified it to fit your format/question. That way you don't need to include it in your question (it's generally preferred that answers and questions are kept separate).

Comment: @Lèse_majesté: Wow, again, thanks! _REALLY_ like your edit, nice.